# Plot a V-shape function given its points

Tags: matlab, plot, interpolation

I have the following matrix which rows are points sampled from a function

```
  f = [   -3.7850  -11.5240
   -3.7753  -11.4822
   -3.7680  -11.5427
   -3.7592  -11.5607
   -3.7576  -11.5461
   -3.7454  -11.5887
   -3.7386  -11.4070
   -3.7358  -11.4450
   -3.7289  -11.5511
   -3.7254  -11.3713
   -3.7122  -11.4515
   -3.6820  -11.5582
   -3.6758  -11.5946
   -3.6732  -11.5823
   -3.6679  -11.6365
   -3.6487  -11.3525
   -3.6424  -11.2745
   -3.6322  -11.3478
   -3.6235  -11.6379
   -3.6159  -11.6308
   -3.5619  -11.1980
   -3.5550  -11.2284
   -3.5544  -11.5925
   -3.5147  -11.6578
   -3.5041  -11.6756
   -3.4860  -11.1550
   -3.4654  -11.6341
   -3.4550  -11.1329
   -3.3802  -11.6701
   -3.3691  -11.1083
   -3.3541  -11.0790
   -3.3485  -11.5887
   -3.3006  -11.6384
   -3.2481  -11.5570
   -3.2459  -11.0268
   -3.2441  -10.9314
   -3.2301  -11.5225
   -3.2270  -10.8832
   -3.1543  -10.8612
   -3.1528  -11.5490
   -3.1167  -11.5021
   -3.1102  -10.8255
   -3.0645  -11.5618
   -2.9967  -11.5420
   -2.9898  -10.8136
   -2.9645  -10.7107
   -2.9211  -11.4197
   -2.9175  -10.6389
   -2.8558  -10.6015
   -2.8327  -11.5108
   -2.7768  -11.4501
   -2.7392  -10.5492
   -2.7217  -11.4230
   -2.6988  -10.4724
   -2.6235  -11.3226
   -2.6196  -11.3806
   -2.5772  -10.4518
   -2.5458  -10.4317
   -2.5014  -10.3176
   -2.4832  -11.3822
   -2.4778  -10.2456
   -2.4029  -11.2907
   -2.3723  -10.3002
   -2.3590  -11.2911
   -2.3491  -10.2110
   -2.2756  -11.2318
   -2.2554  -10.1204
   -2.2542  -10.1411
   -2.2181  -11.2300
   -2.1982   -9.9584
   -2.1645   -9.7938
   -2.1541  -11.1682
   -2.1476   -9.8235
   -2.1451   -9.9205
   -2.1280  -10.0064
   -2.1269   -9.8947
   -2.0898   -9.7926
   -2.0781  -11.1293
   -1.9985  -11.0985
   -1.9249  -11.0443
   -1.8220  -11.0419
   -1.7359  -11.0043
   -1.6924  -10.9775
   -1.6049  -10.9579
   -1.5275  -10.9339
   -1.4757  -10.9113
   -1.4122  -10.8854
   -1.3245  -10.8908
   -1.2936  -10.7893
   -1.2091  -10.8121
   -1.1575  -10.8064
   -1.1237  -10.7105
   -1.0571  -10.7724
   -1.0217  -10.7096
   -0.9717  -10.6984
   -0.9447  -10.7103
   -0.9120  -10.6687
   -0.8908  -10.6670]
```

Plotting by `plot(f(:,1),f(:,2),'+')` it is clear that the function has a V-shape. However, I need to plot it continuously, but doing `plot(f(:,1),f(:,2))` results in a zig-zag function. How can I plot the points as I want to? (beside sorting them manually)

Comment: Besides @PatrickStewart's safe answer below, you could try taking a look at [convhull](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/convhull.html) if you're sure that it's indeed a V (in which case the convex hull is simply a triangle, and you can plot the three extremal points in the proper order). EDIT: I took a look at your data. It's less trivial since your data is noisy. I'll leave this here anyway in case it helps. I would probably try to fit some reasonable function (to the rotated dataset).

Comment: I don't see why you would like to plot a line that goes through exactly all points of scattered data. How should we know the exact order? Perhaps you are looking for a fit instead?

Comment: The ordering would be: before the function turns, sort them in descending order by x; when it turns sort them in ascending order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try rotating your data, sorting it and rotating it back. e.g:

```
theta = -1;
R = [cos(theta) -sin(theta);sin(theta) cos(theta)];
f2 = f*R;
f3 = sortrows(f2);
f4 = f3*R';
plot(f4(:,1),f4(:,2),'-',f(:,1),f(:,2),'+')
```

You can tweak theta to change the angle, which affects the sort order, I just took a guess that -1 is about right.

Comment: Thanks! The plot is ok, I can then smooth it using a moving avg and the result is pretty nice. Thanks again!